# Duo API Directory Sync

Tags: python, python-3.x

By Default Duo Sync runs once Daily, due to the demand of business this needs to be done every 2 hours. looking at DUO API there is a Command for User Sync:

```
python -m duo_client.client --ikey <> --skey <> --host api-<>.duosecurity.com --method POST --path /admin/v1/users username=<> /directorysync/<DIR SYNC>/syncuser
```

However I don't see an API for a general overall sync with the Active Directory So to combat such, I was hoping to get all the users from the 2FA Group and Sync via username over a loop using the following:

```
import sys
import os
import duo_client
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM, ALL_ATTRIBUTES, ALL_OPERATIONAL_ATTRIBUTES, AUTO_BIND_NO_TLS, SUBTREE
from ldap3.core.exceptions import LDAPCursorError

server_name = ''
domain_name = ''
user_name = ''
password = '!'

admin_api = duo_client.Admin(
    ikey= "",
    skey= "",
    host= "api-.duosecurity.com",)

format_string = '{:40}'
print(format_string.format('samaccountname'))

server = Server(server_name, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, user='{}\\{}'.format(domain_name, user_name), password=password, authentication=NTLM,
auto_bind=True)
conn.search('dc={},dc=int'.format(domain_name), '(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=2FA,OU=,OU=,OU=,OU=,DC=,DC=int))',
attributes=[ALL_ATTRIBUTES, ALL_OPERATIONAL_ATTRIBUTES])

for e in sorted(conn.entries):
    print(e.samaccountname)
    os.system("python -m duo_client.client --ikey --skey --host api-.duosecurity.com --method POST --path /admin/v1/users username={}/directorysync//syncuser".format(e.samaccountname))"
```

The above code some what works, but for some users it also re-creates them as the following: User_IDs such as "username/Dir/DIRAPI/usersync". as showing in images below [Duo API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrsDx.png)
[Syncing User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWKZt.png)

Comment: If you print out your last command instead of sending it to os.system does it look correct?  I'm also assuming that your print command for e.samacocuntname returns a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed the username={} was in the wrong

The below is to Create a new user hence why i was seeing username/..../....

Post /admin/v1/users username={}

Below is the Right way for using the API Call.

```
os.system("python -m duo_client.client --ikey --skey --host api-.duosecurity.com --method POST --path /admin/v1/users/directorysync/syncuser username={}".format(e.samaccountname))"
```